# How to find index of multiple objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexof

Here I have `questionDetails.questions` named array inside that array i have 13 objects so I want to find index of all thirteen objects in javascript how it is possible ?

[image]

Comment: I want to find index of all thirteen objects in javascript !! do you mean id ?

Comment: no index I have allready id I want index of this objects

Answer (score 1):

You can just map on the array and get the index, something like this:

```
questionDetails.questions.map(function(item, index){ console.log(index) })
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return any fields in separate array you can use `map` for e.g i return `id`

```
const questionIds = questionDetails.questions.map(question => question.id);
```

or If you want to find any id in your question array or return only that part you can use `filter` e.g

```
const question = questionDetails.questions.filter(question => question.id === 1);
```

Comment: I dont want to find id I want to find indexes of arrays 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 this...

Answer (score 0):

You can find using id

index = questionDetails.questions.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf('35');

Comment: what should I have to put at place of 35 because 35 is static

Comment: you have to use one of the key of object to find its index otherwise how's its possible.If you want to find all just use this logic in loop and supply id one by one

Answer (score 0):

You have a array, you will have array length (Array.length), I think you know a array index will start from 0 to `length - 1`.

A magic function:

```
function getIndexOfArray(arr) {
  let indexes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    indexes.push(i);
  }
  return indexes;
}

let myIndexes = getIndexOfArray(questionDetails.questions);

console.log(myIndexes); // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
// :|
```

I guess that is what you want. (??)